# Using Comparator destroys object "uniqueness"?

Tags: java

Given class User that makes every user unique by it's username and having popularity as a counter for measuring user's popularity is there a way to use TreeSet in order to arrange them by popularity and still retain the uniqueness of the objects inferred by their id.

I tried creating a standard comparator which takes the priorities and subtracts them at first but noticed that when two users have the same amount of popularity only one is added to the TreeSet and to other one is ignored.

After realizing this I tried another comparator that is in the code below and it still doesn't work.

Any advice/articles will be much appreciated.

```java
public class User{

    private int popularity;
    private String username;

 public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        this.popularity = 0;
      
    }

 public void incrementPopularity() {
        this.popularity++;
    }

    public int getPopularity() {
        return this.popularity;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(username, user.username);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username);
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

         // First comparator
         Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<User>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                 return o1.getPopularity() - o2.getPopularity();
           }
            );

        // Second comparator

       Set<User> users2 = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<User>() {
           @Override
           public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
                 if(!o1.equals(o2) && o1.getPopularity() == o2.getPopularity() ) {
                      return -1;
                 }

                 return o1.getPopularity() - o2.getPopularity();
           }
            );
         
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is faulty.

```
             if(!o1.equals(o2) && o1.getPopularity() == o2.getPopularity() ) {
                  return -1;
             }
```

It says that for two users A and B with equal popularity, then A comes before B, and B comes before A.

What you want is to sort on names in the case where the popularities are equal.

```
   public int compare(User o1, User o2) {
      if (o1.getPopularity() == o2.getPopularity())
          return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
      else  
          return Integer.compare(o1.getPopularity(), o2.getPopularity());
   }
```

(assumes a getName method)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to break ties somehow; [the docs for `TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) explicitly point out that two items considered equal by the comparator are treated as duplicates.

Since you have another property that is presumably unique, you can use it to break ties:

```
new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparingInt(User::getPopularity).thenComparing(User::getUsername))
```